# spring validation annotations being ignored when using custom validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I am trying to incorporate annotated validation rules along with some custom validation.  I have a details entity which looks like the following:

```
public class DetailsEntity {    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name is required")
    private String name;
    private String customField;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCustomField() {
        return customField;
    }

    public void setCustomField(String customField) {
        this.customField = customField;
    }
}
```

I then have a controller that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class EntityController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody DetailsEntity create(@RequestBody @Valid
        DetailsEntity details) {
        //Do some creation work
    }
}
```

This all works great out of the box.  The problem is when I try to use a custom validator along with my entity.  My validator looks like this:

```
@Component
public class EntityValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass.isAssignableFrom(DetailsEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        DetailsEntity entity = (DetailsEntity) o;
        if (entity.getCustomField().equals("Some bad value")) {
            errors.reject("Bad custom value supplied");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried injecting my validator two ways.  One is using the `@InitBinder` in the controller, and the other is setting a global validator in the spring configuration (`<mvc:annotation-driven validator="entityValidator" />`).  Either way I do it, the custom validator works fine, but my `@NotEmpty` annotation gets ignored.  How can I use both the annotations as well as a custom validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SpringValidatorAdapter` as base class of your custom validator and override validate() method:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
                // check JSR-303 Constraints
        super.validate(target, errors);
                // Add you custom validation here.

    }
```

Or inject a `LocalValidationFactoryBean` in you custom validator and call to validate(target, errors) before or after your custom validation.

Comment: That send me down the right path, ended up looking at this page: http://nonrepeatable.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-jsr-303-with-classic-spring.html

Comment: I would add that if one want to use group validations, the groups must be added in the the validate method. Otherwise those validations are not executed!

Answer (score 1):

@NotEmpty is a JSR-303 annotation, and we need to use an implementation of it like HiberanteValidator, we need to add Hibernate-Validator jar to your lib directory. Using this jar we can use @NotEmpty, @NotNull...all JSR 303 annotations.

Comment: I came here because I expected Spring to reject my invalid request but it didn't. Fixed by simply adding org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator dependency. This answer is superior to the accepted answer because it utilizes spring built-in functionality instead of doing the hard work yourself.